# Are the T-800 gender masculine only?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Sure, the T-1000 can take a woman figure and the T-X seems like a woman too.
But does the T-800 only have the male gender? Is there a T-800 feminine?

Update>>By Adamant comment, I mean your b option.

Comment: As far as can be told, no. All of the ones seen in the shows and books are male. The T-900 had the option of female.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking: a) Whether certain T-800 Terminator models can only take on the shape of people of a given sex? b) Whether some T-800 Terminators come with a female form as their “default”? c) Whether  T-800 Terminators have a psychological gender, and if so whether that can be female?

Comment: Maybe he's still experimenting...

Comment: Anyway, the Terminator _model_ is independent of their T-number, so why not? In that case, the question becomes, why do we see so few female terminators.

Comment: Terminators are machines, they dont have gender.
They are made to resemble a gender, but in their core they are genderless.

Comment: The [T-803 from the card game](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-803) is female. I'm not sure how canon that card game is considered to be, though.

Comment: @Null - I'd assume 'not at all' given that that's the dancer from the club that Sarah is hiding in.

Comment: I remember a comic from circa T2 (maybe before) that had a female terminator that I assume was a T-800. Might have been one of the vs. Predators/Aliens comics.

Comment: @Darren Now that you say, I remembered too... it was a group of the resistance in a dark room a la tron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 1991 Dark Horse comic series `The Terminator: Secondary Objectives`, there is a female T-800 known as Z000.M.

[She/it was](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Z000.M) ...

> activated by Skynet in response to an incursion by the Resistance cell
>   led by Colonel Mary Randall into a fully functional Skynet network
>   complex six months after John Connor destroyed the Master Control
>   central node. Upon maturation, this unit was immediately deployed via
>   TDE to reinforce C890.L in countering the human offensive. **Z000.M's
>   model appears as a large, muscular Caucasian female with long brown
>   hair.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the Sarah Connor Chronicles there is a female terminator named [Rosie](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Rosie).

She is assumed to be a T-888 model, as she is inferior to [Cameron](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron) (who is either a T-900 or TOK715).

[image]

Comment: Her model number is never confirmed in either the show or the supplementary materials. There's no more reason to assume she's an 800-series than that she's some sort of weird one-off model like [Marcus Wright](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus_Wright)

Comment: Indeed. the linked page says, "appears to be no more advanced than the average T-888" but then it goes on to list more advanced features such as the self-destructing CPU, the improved flexibility of movement etc.